# Install and run tcpshow and pppstats on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new to Linux. I want to run the pppstats and tcpshow commands on Ubuntu 20.04. But I can not do that, can you guide me?

Comment: Perhaps you can try asking in https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Have you tried installing it via `sudo apt-get install pppstats tcpshow`?